# Multidimensional arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Edit: As Adam Washington points out, as from Beta 6, this code works as is, so the question is no longer relevant.

I am trying to create and iterate through a two dimensional array:

```
var array = Array(count:NumColumns, repeatedValue:Array(count:NumRows, repeatedValue:Double()))

array[0][0] = 1
array[1][0] = 2
array[2][0] = 3
array[0][1] = 4
array[1][1] = 5
array[2][1] = 6
array[0][2] = 7
array[1][2] = 8
array[2][2] = 9

for column in 0...2 {
    for row in 0...2 {
        println("column: \(column) row: \(row) value:\(array[column][row])")
    }
}
```

However, this is the output I get:

```
column: 0 row: 0 value:3.0
column: 0 row: 1 value:6.0
column: 0 row: 2 value:9.0
column: 1 row: 0 value:3.0
column: 1 row: 1 value:6.0
column: 1 row: 2 value:9.0
column: 2 row: 0 value:3.0
column: 2 row: 1 value:6.0
column: 2 row: 2 value:9.0
```

It looks as if the last column in the row is overwriting the other column values.

Am I declaring it wrong?

Edit: Perhaps a picture from the Playground would help:

[image: Captured from Playground]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For future readers, here is an elegant solution(5x5):

`var matrix = [[Int]](repeating: [Int](repeating: 0, count: 5), count: 5)`

and a dynamic approach:

```
var matrix = [[Int]]() // creates an empty matrix
var row = [Int]() // fill this row
matrix.append(row) // add this row
```

Comment: var matrix:[[Int]] = [[Int]](repeating:[Int](repeating:0, count:5), count:5) // Swift 3

Answer (score 53):

As stated by the other answers, you are adding the same array of rows to each column. To create a multidimensional array you must use a loop

```
var NumColumns = 27
var NumRows = 52
var array = Array<Array<Double>>()
for column in 0..NumColumns {
    array.append(Array(count:NumRows, repeatedValue:Double()))
}
```

Comment: `Double[][](count: NumColumns, repeatedValue:Double[](count: NumRows, repeatedValue:Double()));` if you don't want a loop

Comment: As of beta 3, the syntax is a little different. Also, this only gets you something useful for arrays of value types -- for reference types you get an array of many references to the same object. More in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24812138/957768).

Comment: Multidimensional array initialization syntax gave me enough fits I wrote this up http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/multidimensional-arrays-in-swift/

Comment: @Literphor, new syntax is `[[Double]](count: NumColumns, repeatedValue:[Double](count: NumRows, repeatedValue:Double()));`

Comment: Changed again? Now it looks like it should be `repeating:` instead of `repeatedValue:` and `repeating:` apparently must go before `count:`

Answer (score 14):

```
var array: Int[][] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for first in array {
    for second in first {
        println("value \(second)")
    }
}
```

To achieve what you're looking for you need to initialize the array to the correct template and then loop to add the row and column arrays:

```
var NumColumns = 27
var NumRows = 52
var array = Array<Array<Int>>()
var value = 1

for column in 0..NumColumns {
    var columnArray = Array<Int>()
    for row in 0..NumRows {
        columnArray.append(value++)
    }
    array.append(columnArray)
}

println("array \(array)")
```

Comment: Yes, I can see that the declaration done this way works, but I would like to declare the array without initializing each bit.

In the Swift Playground my declaration works, and shows the array as I want it to look:
`[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]`

But if I put 

`var a = Array(count:4, repeatedValue:Array(count:3, repeatedValue:Double()))` then 

`a[1][1] = 99` then 

`a`

into the Playground, I get the result `[[0.0, 99.0, 0.0], [0.0, 99.0, 0.0], [0.0, 99.0, 0.0]]`

Comment: In your array creation you're creating one array and repeating the same array three times.  You're not creating three unique arrays.

Comment: So what would be the syntax to create a multidimensional array of 52 rows and 27 columns?

Comment: @Caroline `Double[][](count: 27, repeatedValue:Double[](count: 52, repeatedValue:Double()));`

Answer (score 6):

Your problem may have been due to a deficiency in an earlier version of Swift or of the Xcode Beta. Working with Xcode Version 6.0 (6A279r) on August 21, 2014, your code works as expected with this output:

```
column: 0 row: 0 value:1.0
column: 0 row: 1 value:4.0
column: 0 row: 2 value:7.0
column: 1 row: 0 value:2.0
column: 1 row: 1 value:5.0
column: 1 row: 2 value:8.0
column: 2 row: 0 value:3.0
column: 2 row: 1 value:6.0
column: 2 row: 2 value:9.0
```

I just copied and pasted your code into a Swift playground and defined two constants:

```
let NumColumns = 3, NumRows = 3
```

Comment: Yes - I think they did change something in that area. I've edited the question. Thanks :)

Comment: And you changed println to print

Answer (score 4):

Using http://blog.trolieb.com/trouble-multidimensional-arrays-swift/ as a start, I added generics to mine:

```
class Array2DTyped<T>{

var cols:Int, rows:Int
var matrix:[T]

init(cols:Int, rows:Int, defaultValue:T){
    self.cols = cols
    self.rows = rows
    matrix = Array(count:cols*rows,repeatedValue:defaultValue)
}

subscript(col:Int, row:Int) -> T {
    get{
        return matrix[cols * row + col]
    }
    set{
        matrix[cols * row + col] = newValue
    }
}

func colCount() -> Int {
    return self.cols
}

func rowCount() -> Int {
    return self.rows
}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what 'matrix[cols * row + col]' mean?

Comment: @Max_Power89 Try to draw on a paper a 3x3 matrix then imagine this matrix to be on a single line (so the second line goes at the end of the first line and so on). Basically, when you are at the first column & second row, it is the same thing as being at the fourth item. This is what `cols * row + col` means.

Comment: https://github.com/qiter/swift_astarPath/blob/fee1dc501572592cf8970d79963016ef8614368d/Qt_astar/astar/Array2DTyped.swift

Comment: This is very similar to what I've done. This particular way of dealing with multidimensional arrays allows you to still get at the 1-D version of the array which can be useful if manipulations on the dataset are independent of its row-column position. An example would be if each cell contained RGB pixel data and you wanted to convert it to black and white.

Comment: @johndpope in your gist you roll through the array's rows and columns to locate an element. Why not just search the 1-D version of the array and calculate row-column? row = index / columns, column = index % columns

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an array of three elements and assigning all three to the same thing, which is itself an array of three elements (three Doubles).

When you do the modifications you are modifying the floats in the internal array.

Answer (score 1):

Your original logic for creating the matrix is indeed correct, and it even works in Swift 2. The problem is that in the print loop, you have the row and column variables reversed. If you change it to:

```
for row in 0...2 {
  for column in 0...2 {
    print("column: \(column) row: \(row) value:\(array[column][row])")

  }
}
```

you will get the correct results. Hope this helps!