# How to create multidimensional array in swift?

Tags: multidimensional-array, nsmutablearray, nsarray, swift

I'm trying to push array type object to special index inside array in new Swift lang by Apple. It should look like this = `[ [...], [...], ...]`, as I've read in the docs - `NSMutableArray` type is assigned to variable automatically if it's `var`, but even in playground it throws me errors:

```
var arr = [];

arr[0] = []; // Error: cannot assign to result of this expression

arr.insert([], atIndex:0) // Error: 'NSArray' does not have member named 'insert'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24052260/359578

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var array2d: [[Int]] = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

Comment: Thanks I managed to fix this with this code - ``var arr = Array<Array<MyCustomClass>>()``, but I didn't get yet how to init array with the syntax you proposed.

Comment: The newest beta has changed this syntax to be more like [[Int]] = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]

Comment: Updated the answer to show the new syntax.