# How to create Swift empty two dimensional array with size

Tags: arrays, swift

I try to do smth like this:

```
let myArray: [[MyClass]] = [5,5]
```

where [5,5] is size of array.
I can't do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051490/multidimensional-arrays-in-swift

Comment: @Wabonano: that answer has caveats that applied only to the pre-beta3 `Array` behavior. cadaster's answer works on beta 3... with other caveats.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want to make a multidimensional array of value types (i.e. `Int`s, `String`s, structs), the syntax in codester's answer works great:

**Swift 4**

```
var arr = [[Int]](repeating: [Int](repeating: 0, count: 5), count: 5)
```

**Swift Earlier**

```
var arr = [[Int]](count: 5, repeatedValue: [Int](count: 5, repeatedValue: 0))
arr[0][1] = 1
// arr is [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], ...
```

If you make a multidimensional array of reference types (i.e. classes), this gets you an array of many references to the same object:

```
class C {
    var v: Int = 0
}
var cArr = [[C]](count: 5, repeatedValue: [C](count: 5, repeatedValue: C()))
// cArr is [[{v 0}, {v 0}, {v 0}, {v 0}, {v 0}], ...
cArr[0][1].v = 1
// cArr is [[{v 1}, {v 1}, {v 1}, {v 1}, {v 1}], ...
```

If you want to make an array (uni- or multidimensional) of reference types, you might be better off either making the array dynamically:

```
var cArr = [[C]]()
for _ in 0..<5 {
    var tmp = [C]()
    for _ in 0..<5 {
        tmp += C()
    }
    cArr += tmp
}
// cArr is [[{v 0}, {v 0}, {v 0}, {v 0}, {v 0}], ...
cArr[0][1].v = 1
// cArr is [[{v 0}, {v 1}, {v 0}, {v 0}, {v 0}], ...
```

(See [slazyk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24812129/957768) for equivalent shorter syntax using `map()`.)

Or making an array of optionals and filling in their values:

```
var optArr = [[C?]](count: 5, repeatedValue: [C?](count: 5, repeatedValue: nil))
// optArr is [[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil], ...
optArr[0][1] = C()
// optArr is [[nil, {v 0}, nil, nil, nil], ...
```

Comment: It might be worth additionally noting, that in the last code snippet (and the first as well), having a repeated value of [C?] (and [Int]) is fine because (from Beta 3 on) arrays are value types with full value semantics.

Comment: @rickster If I could I'd gave you 1000 ups. Thank you. Really looking for that

Comment: Great answer. What would the pointer look like for an array of optionals before initialization? Like this?: var optArr: [[C?]]

Answer (score 5):

Creating 5x5 array filled with *distinct* objects of the same class.
Maybe not the prettiest solution, but a working one, and avoiding the for loops:

```
let myArray = [[MyClass]](map(0..<5) { _ in
    [MyClass](map(0..<5) { _ in
        MyClass()
    })
})
```

**Edit:**
Since the question was actually to create 'empty' array with 'size', I'd have to add that you cannot have it 'empty' if it is not of an optional type. But if that is what you want, you can also do it as [rickster suggests at the bottom of his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24812138/2046564) and just create 5x5 array of `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the accepted answer, in Swift 3, the syntax is slightly different:

```
var arr = [[Int]](repeating: [Int](repeating: 0, count: 5), count: 5)
```

Note the order of arguments and `repeating` instead of `repeatedValue`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by following code it will intialize the two dimensional array with same default value which in this case is **same instance of `MyClass`** object and this is not that great.In case you need different objects you need to make `for-loop` to intialize the objects.But in case for same instance the following code will work.This code is better for primitive type like `Int` or `structs` `String` but not for `Classes`.But in case i am showing the syntax for two dimensional array intialization

```
let myArray: [[MyClass]] = [[MyClass]](count: 5, repeatedValue:[MyClass](count: 5, repeatedValue:MyClass()));
```

better would be to use primitive data types and `stuct`

It will fill the array with two dimentional `MyClass` objects.As default value is needed in `Swift` if you are providing size.
From Swift programming guide

> “Swift’s Array type also provides an initializer for creating an array
>   of a certain size with all of its values set to a provided default
>   value. You pass this initializer the number of items to be added to
>   the new array (called count) and a default value of the appropriate
>   type ”

---

As of now i do not know any way to just `intialize` its memory but not to fill the array in `Swift` of certain size.Above code will fill default `MyClass` objects of 5*5.

Comment: This will make all elements of the 5x5 array be references to the same `MyClass` instance, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @rickster you are right it will create 5*5 array with same `MyClass` instance as it is default value and have same value for all elements of array

Comment: is that a 5x5 array or a 5x5 array ?

Answer (score 1):

For two dimensional array with different dimension of each component (not square matrix) you may write

```
var arr2D: [[Int]] = [Array<Int>(repeating: 1, count:2), Array<Int>(repeating: 2, count:3)]
```