# Multi Dimensional Array in Swift

Tags: swift

I need to create a multi dimensional array in swift that would be the equivalent to this is php:

```
$thing["field_name"]["und"][0] = "value"
```

or

```
   $thing[field_user_phone] => Array (
      [und] => Array (
         [0] => Array (
           [value] => 9496665555
         )
      )
    )
```

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051490/multidimensional-arrays-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way in swift:

```
var storage:Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Array<String>>> = ["filed_name":["und":["value"]]]

storage["newfield"] = ["test":["aa"]]
```