# What's the best way to store a value in swift so that I can return the cell result of an x axis y axis?

Tags: ios, swift

My data looks like an simple price chart with hours on the X axis and mileage on the Y. The matrix of these should return the price.

Can you tell me the best way to store data in Swift to achieve this and how to access it?

Comment: Your price gets calculated from your X and Y value, or is this a specific value? Do you need any Identifier for each key/value pair, or do you only want to display a simple chart?

Comment: The X and Y value do not calculate the specific value they are only there to indicate the exact cell. I don't want to display the chart just the result of a query such as getPrice(xAxis: 5, yAxis: 200)

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051490/multidimensional-arrays-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have 2 Values and one Identifier - this is the Key for each Key Value Pair.

I would use a simple Dictionary. For example like this:

```
var points = [Float : [Int : Float]]()
```

// add Custom Value

```
points[10000] = [8 : 324.42]
points[10001] = [10 : 324.4241]
```

// get point Value

```
for (price, values) in points {

    println(price)

    for (hours, mileage) in values {

        println(hours)
        println(mileage)

    }

}
```