# How to insert values into a multidimensional array in a loop swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Couldnt find the answer to this.

I am trying to insert values into a multi dimensional array with something like this

```
_ = transportRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshotOne) in

        self.yearList.insert(snapshotOne.key, atIndex: 0)

        //print("snapshotone.key " + snapshotOne.key) // prints year

        if let snapshotTwo = snapshotOne.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            for itemTwo in snapshotTwo {

                self.monthList[self.counter].insert(itemTwo.key, atIndex: 0)
            }
         }

         counter += 1
}
```

my `counter` is in another loop outside this one. The thing is I receive an erro `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` and after playing around in Playground, I realise it is because my `monthList: [[String]] = [[]]` and therefore there isnt any array to insert or something like that. If I were to give it some init like `monthList = [["1"], ["2"]]` then I would be able to insert till `monthList[1]` before it gives an error for `monthList[2]`

help? thanks

Comment: Show your code and provide details of the error.

Comment: See also: [Multidimensional arrays in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24051490/1445366)

Comment: I have added more details @matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare your array of arrays, your outer array is empty.  In order to insert values into the multidimensional array, you need to create the inner arrays and add them to the outer array.

You could do this by adding a `while` loop that adds more inner arrays until you have enough to insert to:

```
for item in itemsOne {
    while counter >= monthList.count {
        monthList.append([String]())
    }
    monthList[counter].insert(item.key, atIndex: 0)
}
```

If you know ahead of time that `counter` is a value from `0...29` for instance, you could create the inner arrays like this:

```
var monthList = [[String]](count:30, repeatedValue:[])
```

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to initialize each array in your second dimension before trying to add to that array, I don't know if you are actually doing this or not because the code snippet provided is very small. Also I believe arrays in swift are mutable, so you could just do this:

```
monthList[counter] = [String]()

for item in itemsOne { 
    monthList[counter].append(item.key) 
}
```

This way by using append you can dynamically insert elements into your array. Otherwise you would need another counter variable to increment for your atIndex parameter for your insert method because in your code the atIndex in the insert method was always inserting at index 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer! makes sense. but execution should be like vacawama

Comment: @Chris yes, vacuwama answer is a nicer solution than mine, so no worries. I don't know much about swift or it's syntax, I just notice the possible logical error of trying to add element in your second dimension array without that array being initialized first, it is an error that would happen in most programming languages. vacuwama answer is a better answer to be accepted for others to see : )