# Swift - Convert array to multidimensional array

Tags: swift

Those are the array models:

```
struct UserModel: Codable {
    var userid: Int
    var nickname: String
}

struct UserModelSplit: Codable {
    var usr: [UserModel]
}
```

Initialising them:

```
@State private var users = [UserModel]()
@State private var userSplit = [UserModelSplit]()
```

Getting the first array:

```
for bla in userReceived{
    users.append(UserModel(userid: bla.userid, nickname: bla.nickname))
}
```

Now I want to split it to the multidimensional array so the result should be:

```
userSplit[0][0] // 1th user
userSplit[0][1] // 2th user
userSplit[0][2] // 3th user
userSplit[0][3] // 4th user
userSplit[1][0] // 5th user
userSplit[1][1] // 6th user
userSplit[1][2] // 7th user
userSplit[1][3] // 8th user
```

I tried all kind of syntaxes and looked up how it could be done without finding anythi useful.

This is the pseudo code which sums up what I've tried:

```
var current = 0
var added = 0
for val in users{
    userSplit[current][added] = val
    
    added += 1
    if(added == 3){
        current += 1
        added = 0
    }
}
```

This pseudo code is similar to how it would actually work in PHP

I hope it's understandable :D

Comment: When you wrote `userSplit[0][0] // 1th user` did you actually mean `userSplit[0].usr[0]` ?

Comment: Is the goal to group 4 elements per `UserModelSplit` no matter how many elements are in the `users` array? What if there are 6 or 7 users? What if there are 9 or 10, etc.? Please better explain your desired logic.

Comment: Are you saying you want an `[[UserModel]]` where the inner array is blocks of 3 users from the main sequence?  (or blocks of 4 if you use the example output rather than the pseudocode!)

Comment: Yeah :D Now that I added this detail: userSplit[current].usr[added] = val I get the error: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range" on this line, how to do solve this?

Comment: If there are like 6 users then: userSplit[0][0] // 1th user
userSplit[0][1] // 2th user
userSplit[0][2] // 3th user
userSplit[0][3] // 4th user
userSplit[1][0] // 5th user
userSplit[1][1] // 6th user and stop here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multidimensional arrays in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051490/multidimensional-arrays-in-swift)

Comment: Not really since I wouldn't know how to use that on custom array which I have, I'm new to swift @vauxhall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close, to make a 2D array you can do it like this.

```
struct UserModel: Codable {
    var userid: Int
    var nickname: String
}

var users : [UserModel] = (1...20).map({ n in
    UserModel(userid: n, nickname: UUID().uuidString)
})

//Change this number to make the sub arrays the size that you want.
let size = 3

//User Split as a 2D Array
var userSplit : [[UserModel]] = stride(from: 0, to: users.count, by: size).map {
    users[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, users.count)].map{$0}
}

for splitIdx in userSplit.indices{
    print(splitIdx)
    for userIdx in userSplit[splitIdx].indices {
        print(userSplit[splitIdx][userIdx])
    }
}
```

Using the other model you have it should be something like this...

```
struct UserModelSplit: Codable {
    var usr: [UserModel]
}
//Array<UserModelSplit>   NOT 2D Array
var userSplit : [UserModelSplit] = stride(from: 0, to: users.count, by: size).map {
    UserModelSplit(usr: users[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, users.count)].map{$0})
}

for splitIdx in userSplit.indices{
    print(splitIdx)
    for userIdx in userSplit[splitIdx].usr.indices {
        print(userSplit[splitIdx].usr[userIdx])
    }
}
```

With both of those scenarios you will get print out that looks something like

[image]

The biggest reason your code doesn't work is because in swift you can only use

```
array[index] = something
```

to replace an existing value.

You have to

```
array.append(something)
```

when you are creating a new index.

You can split any array into a 2D array with an `Array` `extension`

```
extension Array {
    func split(_ size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

Then use

```
//User Split as a 2D Array
var userSplit : [[UserModel]] = users.split(size)
```

Comment: Jesus :D This will take a while now since the models were simplified for the question, I'm gonna accept as soon as it works or ask further questions in case it doesn't

Comment: @user19559647 this code works in playground just make sure you know the difference between a 2D array and an array of objects that contain another array

Comment: Is the purpose of the `.map{$0}` to convert an ArraySlice into an Array? That seems less obvious than `Array(users[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, users.count)])`.

Comment: @HangarRash yes I wanted to illustrate types without slice, but your way works too

Comment: Alright the first solution works and I'm sure the second one will too, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sequence method to iterate through your collection and initialize each subsequence into a new collection of its elements:

```
extension Collection {
    var quadruplets: [[Element]] {
        .init(
            sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
                guard start < endIndex else { return nil }
                let end = index(start, offsetBy: 4, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
                defer { start = end }
                return .init(self[start..<end])
            }
        )
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
struct UserModel: Codable {
    let userid: Int
    let nickname: String
}

let users = [
    (1,"a"),
    (2,"b"),
    (3,"c"),
    (4,"d"),
    (5,"e"),
    (6,"f"),
    (7,"g"),
    (8,"h"),
    (9,"i"),
    (10,"j"),
].map(UserModel.init)

let userSplit = users.quadruplets

userSplit[0][0].nickname  // "a"
userSplit[0][1].nickname  // "b"
userSplit[0][2].nickname  // "c"
userSplit[0][3].nickname  // "d"
userSplit[1][0].nickname  // "e"
userSplit[1][1].nickname  // "f"
userSplit[1][2].nickname  // "g"
userSplit[1][3].nickname  // "h"
userSplit[2][0].nickname  // "i"
userSplit[2][1].nickname  // "j"
```

---

**edit/update**:

If you don't want to duplicate the collection elements you can just iterate the original collection subsequences. Something like:

```
extension Collection {
    func unfoldSubSequences(limitedTo maxLength: Int) -> UnfoldSequence<SubSequence,Index> {
        sequence(state: startIndex) { start in
            guard start < endIndex else { return nil }
            let end = index(start, offsetBy: maxLength, limitedBy: endIndex) ?? endIndex
            defer { start = end }
            return self[start..<end]
        }
    }
    func subSequences(limitedTo maxLength: Int) -> [SubSequence] { .init(unfoldSubSequences(limitedTo: maxLength))
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let subSequences = users.subSequences(limitedTo: 4)

subSequences[0][0].nickname  // "a"
subSequences[0][1].nickname  // "b"
subSequences[0][2].nickname  // "c"
subSequences[0][3].nickname  // "d"
subSequences[1][4].nickname  // "e"
subSequences[1][5].nickname  // "f"
subSequences[1][6].nickname  // "g"
subSequences[1][7].nickname  // "h"
subSequences[2][8].nickname  // "i"
subSequences[2][9].nickname  // "j"

for subsequence in subSequences {
    for user in subsequence {
        print(user)
    }
}
```

---

This will print

> UserModel(userid: 1, nickname: "a")
> UserModel(userid: 2, nickname: "b")
> UserModel(userid: 3, nickname: "c")
> UserModel(userid: 4, nickname: "d")
> UserModel(userid: 5, nickname: "e")
> UserModel(userid: 6, nickname: "f")
> UserModel(userid: 7, nickname: "g")
> UserModel(userid: 8, nickname: "h")
> UserModel(userid: 9, nickname: "i")
> UserModel(userid: 10, nickname: "j")

---

And to make it complete you can extend RangeReplaceableCollection as follow. This would work with Strings as well (Collection of Characters):

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func groups(limitedTo maxLength: Int) -> [Self] {
        subSequences(limitedTo: maxLength).map(Self.init)
    }
}

let quadruplets = "abcdefghij".groups(limitedTo: 4)

quadruplets[0]  // "abcd"
quadruplets[1]  // "efgh"
quadruplets[2]  // "ij"
```

Comment: Wow this one looks handy, will try it out too!

Comment: Note that this will duplicate all elements of your array. This is needed to be able to zero the original elements indices.

Comment: If you can just iterate the collection subsequences I can show you how to not dup0licate the collection elements

Comment: It works perfectly, will definitively use this additionally in other views, thanks!